# Can you find the wordpress theme of a website?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Can anybody find what's the wordpress theme is this site using ? http://alfakhamaholidays.com/

Comment: That is not a wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think https://themeforest.net/user/nicdark?ref=nicdark
check it http://nicdarkthemes.com/ find here may be u got

Comment: actually how did you find it ?

Comment: ctrl + u and see script and styles

Answer (score 3):

It is not developed using WordPress at all. For more information you can check it here : https://builtwith.com/alfakhamaholidays.com

Comment: Yes, looks like not a WordPress site. However it uses Revolution Slider which is very popular in WordPress community that might have given the impression to OP that it was a WP site.